# How to produce a DataFrame which repeats the data of one depending on the number of another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frames:

DataFrame `a`:

```
|---------------------| 
|        month        |
|---------------------|
|      2017-02-01     |
|---------------------|
|      2017-03-01     |
|---------------------|
|      2017-04-01     |
|---------------------|
|      2017-05-01     |
|---------------------|
|      2017-06-01     |
|---------------------|
```

DataFrame `b`:

```
|------------|---------------------|-----------------| 
|     beds   |        model        |       units     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|
|      1     |         0.14        |        5        |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|
|      2     |         0.26        |        9        |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|
```

and I need to produce the following DataFrame:

```
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------| 
|     beds   |        model        |       units     |        month        |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      1     |         0.14        |        5        |      2017-02-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      1     |         0.14        |        5        |      2017-03-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      1     |         0.14        |        5        |      2017-04-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      1     |         0.14        |        5        |      2017-05-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      1     |         0.14        |        5        |      2017-06-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      2     |         0.26        |        9        |      2017-02-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      2     |         0.26        |        9        |      2017-03-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      2     |         0.26        |        9        |      2017-04-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      2     |         0.26        |        9        |      2017-05-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
|      2     |         0.26        |        9        |      2017-06-01     |
|------------|---------------------|-----------------|---------------------|
```

I was thinking about using a for loop, but I wonder if there is a way to do it on pandas without using for loops. The point is for each row in `b` have a new row with a corresponding month in `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can produce a new `pd.MultiIndex` from the values of `a`s months and `b`s index.  Then `reindex` on the specified level of the `pd.MultiIndex`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([b.index, a.month], names=[None, 'month'])
# included `reset_index(drop=True) on the advice from `@jezrael` 
# this replaces the non-unique index with a unique index
b.reindex(mux, level=0).reset_index('month').reset_index(drop=True)

        month  beds  model  units
0  2017-02-01     1   0.14      5
1  2017-03-01     1   0.14      5
2  2017-04-01     1   0.14      5
3  2017-05-01     1   0.14      5
4  2017-06-01     1   0.14      5
5  2017-02-01     2   0.26      9
6  2017-03-01     2   0.26      9
7  2017-04-01     2   0.26      9
8  2017-05-01     2   0.26      9
9  2017-06-01     2   0.26      9
```

---

***Simple and Fast***

```
%%timeit
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([b.index, a.month], names=[None, 'month'])
b.reindex(mux, level=0).reset_index('month')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop

%timeit a.assign(id=1).merge(b.assign(id=1)).drop('id',1).sort_values("beds")
100 loops, best of 3: 3.23 ms per loop

%%timeit
c = np.tile(a['month'].values, len(b.index))
d = np.repeat(b.index.values, len(a.index))
df = pd.DataFrame(b.values[d], index= b.index[d], columns=b.columns).assign(month=c)
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))
df[['beds','units']] = df[['beds','units']].astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hmmm, in larger df it is fast too?

Comment: And forget reset index - removing duplicates index values ;)

Comment: @piRSquared, I tried your solution, but I am getting `MultiIndex` object and I need a DataFrame

Comment: `df = b.reindex(mux, level=0).reset_index('month').reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Nice answer. I'm trying to reproduce your answer, but can't cleanly read the dataframes with `pd.readclipboard`? Is there a trick to read these dfs that are constructed with dashes?

Comment: @moondra yes!, paste it to an editor of some sort and delete the lines with dashes.  Then `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python', usecols=[1, 2, 3])`... or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

`Numpy` solution with [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for repeating:

```
c = np.tile(a['month'].values, len(b.index))
d = np.repeat(b.index.values, len(a.index))
df = pd.DataFrame(b.values[d], index= b.index[d], columns=b.columns).assign(month=c)
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))
df[['beds','units']] = df[['beds','units']].astype(int)
print (df)

   beds  model  units      month
0     1   0.14      5 2017-02-01
1     1   0.14      5 2017-03-01
2     1   0.14      5 2017-04-01
3     1   0.14      5 2017-05-01
4     1   0.14      5 2017-06-01
5     2   0.26      9 2017-02-01
6     2   0.26      9 2017-03-01
7     2   0.26      9 2017-04-01
8     2   0.26      9 2017-05-01
9     2   0.26      9 2017-06-01

print (df.dtypes)
beds              int32
model           float64
units             int32
month    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Another solution:

```
c = np.tile(a['month'].values, len(b.index))
d = np.tile(b.values, len(a.index)).reshape(-1,len(b.columns))
print (d)
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=b.columns).assign(month=c)
df[['beds','units']] = df[['beds','units']].astype(int)
print (df)
   beds  model  units      month
0     1   0.14      5 2017-02-01
1     1   0.14      5 2017-03-01
2     1   0.14      5 2017-04-01
3     1   0.14      5 2017-05-01
4     1   0.14      5 2017-06-01
5     2   0.26      9 2017-02-01
6     2   0.26      9 2017-03-01
7     2   0.26      9 2017-04-01
8     2   0.26      9 2017-05-01
9     2   0.26      9 2017-06-01
```

Comment: Yes, it is simplier, but obviously slowier. So if very large df, `numpy` is better.

Comment: I didn't know that, so I am going to use `%timeit` to see the time of both solutions

Answer (score 2):

`merge` will make cartesian product for duplicated values in the *merge* column, so you can create a constant column on both data frames and merge on it:

```
df = a.assign(id=1).merge(b.assign(id=1)).drop('id',1)
df.sort_values("beds")

#       month  beds  model  units
#0  2017-02-01  1   0.14    5
#2  2017-03-01  1   0.14    5
#4  2017-04-01  1   0.14    5
#6  2017-05-01  1   0.14    5
#8  2017-06-01  1   0.14    5
#1  2017-02-01  2   0.26    9
#3  2017-03-01  2   0.26    9
#5  2017-04-01  2   0.26    9
#7  2017-05-01  2   0.26    9
#9  2017-06-01  2   0.26    9
```

Comment: thanks, why do you need to use `assign(id=1)`? and I thought that `merge()` by default performed an inner join.

Comment: `assign(id=1)` is meant to create a constant column on the data frame as the join key so that the result will be a cartesian product of the two data frames.